# Cannot get array length to a variable in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular project with a search function. I need to print the search item count with a search. To do a search, I'm filtering the JSON object with the search term and create a new array called filterarray. Then I take the length of filterarray and print it as well. But I need to print it in another component called search-count.component. To do that I use a shareable service called count.service. The problem is, when I print the array length in HTML bind, It will print correctly but search-count component has value 0 alywas.

Search-Component.ts:

```
export class SearchResultComponent implements OnInit {

  _postsArray: JsoncallItem[] = []; //JSON-array
  value: string = ''; //search-term
  filterarray: any = []; //filtered-array
  count:string; //filtered-array-length

  constructor(private data: SendDataService, private tot: CountService){}

  getData(){
    this.data.currentValue.subscribe(value => {this.value = value;
      this.showData();
    })
  }

  showData(){
    if (this.value != null){
      this.filterarray=
        this._postsArray.filter(f => 
          f.title.toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.value.toLowerCase()))
              .map(searchname=>searchname)
    }
  }

  newCount(){
    this.tot.currentCount.subscribe(count => this.count = count);
    this.tot.changeCount(this.filterarray.length);
  }

    ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getData();
    this.newCount();
  }

}
```

Search-Component.html:

```
{{filterarray.length}}
//show correct length
```

search-count.ts:

```
export class SearchCountComponent implements OnInit {

  count: any;

  constructor(private tot: CountService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.tot.currentCount.subscribe(count => this.count = count);
  }
}
```

search-count.html:

```
{{count}}
//show 0 always
```

count.service

```
export class CountService {

  private countSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  currentCount = this.countSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeCount(count: string) {
    this.countSource.next(count)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not returning directly the behaviousSubject? : getCount() : Observable<any>{ return this.countSource.asObservable();}

Comment: you mean instead of subscription in search-count.ts?

Comment: `console.log(this.filterarray.length)` check if it is showing correct value or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. The problem is I call `this.newCount();` in `ngOnInit()` so that **It execute before updating the filterarray**. It solved by move `this.newCount();` into `getData()` function like this:

```js
getData() {
  this.data.currentValue.subscribe(value => {
    this.value = value;
    this.showData();
    this.newCount();
  })
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use AfterViewInit than OnInit so the value will be updated whenever the length of filterarray is changed
you can use AfterViewInit like this

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.tot.currentCount.subscribe(count => this.count = count);
  }
```